# Wordpress Unexpected margin on html, body

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a WordPress Theme from Scratch. I'm new in WordPress theming, when I put my local website on wordpress I got an unexpected margin. Don't know where its come form.

Its look like this, Margin on top,

[image: Unexpected Margin]

When I inspected, I got This, Can't understand from where the code comes,

[image: Inspect]

Anyone please help me,

Note: I'm working on local, So that I can't provide any link or code.

Comment: Does logging out of Wordpress solve the problem? Could be the admin toolbar....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress reserves this space for the Admin toolbar when you are logged in. It can be disabled in profile settings.

Comment: I understand, Thanks, Can you please provide me any link where I can learn about wordpress Theming.

Comment: I haven't built a theme in quite a while, I think the WordPress codex is good, or there are plenty of tutorials for beginners.. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/theme-development/

Answer (score 1):

This margin is provided to the tool bar when log in to the wordpress site. It can be disabled and when you logout it will work fine.

Comment: I understand, Thanks, Can you please provide me any link where I can learn about wordpress Theming.

Comment: Please check the link. It is very helpful for any course `https://www.lynda.com` . Please mark the answer if you found it helpful